# XML to POJO JAVA

Tags: java, xml

I have read other posts related to this issue but I could not fix my problem. I try to convert the following XML String to a JAVA class but when I try to access param1 using `getParam1()` method it returns null and I am not sure why.

The XML String:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<REQUERYTRXRESPONSE xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
 <param1>3gbahtJf1y85Oks4HrPLkqTQZV8Yg8pIhdXOrZ8pLGJP3FLwqKlIzIl/GgUpGvFaw4MC4SV+4pCudmVq+apIMIJJS4PrVyUx4T0ZO/Tsui4ZqCn62dLAG0DVhBVz2ZasF4yr7CRYnk47FWS0RywXmA==</param1>
 <param2>lO4ismiJwsvBiHQGW/UwCA==</param2>
 <param3 />
</REQUERYTRXRESPONSE>
```

The Java class:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(namespace = "http://tempuri.org/", name =  "REQUERYTRXRESPONSE")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY)
public class REQUERYTRXRESPONSE {
private String param1;
private String param2;
private String param3;

@XmlElement(required = true, name = "param1")
public String getParam1() {
    return param1;
}
public void setParam1(String param1) {
    this.param1 = param1;
}

@XmlElement(required = true, name = "param2")
public String getParam2() {
    return param2;
}
public void setParam2(String param2) {
    this.param2 = param2;
}

@XmlElement(required = true, name = "param3")
public String getParam3() {
    return param3;
}
public void setParam3(String param3) {
    this.param3 = param3;
}
}
```

The XML to Java class code:

```
HttpRequest httpRequest = HttpRequest.get();

    if (httpRequest.ok()) {
        String response = httpRequest.body();

        System.out.println(response);

        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(REQUERYTRXRESPONSE.class);
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        REQUERYTRXRESPONSE requerytrxresponse = (REQUERYTRXRESPONSE) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StringReader(response));


        System.out.println((String) requerytrxresponse.getParam1()); // returns null
    }
```

Comment: Can you print the response to the console to check if it in fact has the correct XML content?  This would be the first thing I would check.

Comment: I think you need to annotate the setters.

Comment: @shmosel I don't think so

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the xml string above is the result of printing the response to console. I copy it from the console.

Comment: Just a hint: In the future, simple create a marshaller from the context, instantiate an object from your class, marshall it to a file. This way, you can see what XML your class defines and then work on the differences from there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Managed to figure it out.

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "REQUERYTRXRESPONSE")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Response {

   private String param1;
   private String param2;
   private String param3;

   public String getParam1() {
      return param1;
   }

   public void setParam1(String param1) {
      this.param1 = param1;
   }

   public String getParam2() {
      return param2;
   }

   public void setParam2(String param2) {
      this.param2 = param2;
   }

   public String getParam3() {
      return param3;
   }

   public void setParam3(String param3) {
      this.param3 = param3;
   }
```

}

You don't need to specify the `@XmlElement` when you do the `@XxmlAccessorType` unless you wanted the `required=true` part.

What I changed is that I moved the namespace from `@XmlRootElement` in a `package-info.java` class like so:

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "http://tempuri.org/",
        elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package com.sfatandrei.soplayground.model;
```

My main test method includes:

```
  final InputStream resourceAsStream = SoPlaygroundApplication.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("test.xml");
  JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Response.class);
  Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
  Response response = (Response) unmarshaller.unmarshal(resourceAsStream);
  System.out.println(response);
```

Comment: Actually you don't need any annotations whatsoever, unless you want non default behavior.

Comment: Alternatively, you could also simply have copied the namespace declaration into the elements, too. The problem was, that your class did not reflect the xml : The class says "the elements have no namespace" but the xml defines verything being in `http://tempuri.org/`.

Comment: You are correct, @FlorianSchaetz, but from a readability and maintainability point of view, the package-info.java is a easier way for this.

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz Thanks, it was very helpful

Answer (score 1):

For me it works just fine. Make sure that you've got a proper encoding and check your jaxb provider. I tested it with default sun implementation - com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.

Make a test for your unmarshalling code:

```
@Test
public void testUnmarshaller() throws JAXBException, IOException {
    final InputStream expectedXmlResource = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/REQUERYTRXRESPONSE.xml");
    StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
    IOUtils.copy(expectedXmlResource, stringWriter, "UTF-8");

    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(REQUERYTRXRESPONSE .class);
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
    REQUERYTRXRESPONSE requerytrxresponse = (REQUERYTRXRESPONSE) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StringReader(stringWriter.toString()));

    assertEquals(requerytrxresponse.getParam1(), "3gbahtJf1y85Oks4HrPLkqTQZV8Yg8pIhdXOrZ8pLGJP3FLwqKlIzIl/GgUpGvFaw4MC4SV+4pCudmVq+apIMIJJS4PrVyUx4T0ZO/Tsui4ZqCn62dLAG0DVhBVz2ZasF4yr7CRYnk47FWS0RywXmA==");
}
```